# How to pass more than two parameters(Text, Value) in LIstItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dirArr)
{
   files.Add(new ListItem(Text, Value));
}

GridView.DataSource=files;
GridView.DataBind();
```

How to pass parameters as following, It is allowing to pass only two parameters

```
files.Add(new ListItem(Text, Value, FirstNamee, LastName, Addresss));
```

Comment: What about `ListItem`? You have to add these parameters to the constructor of class `ListItem`

Comment: Well, how about a class?

Comment: why DirectoryInfo folder (not use in your code)

Comment: @MegaTron  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASP.NET [`ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx) has only a `Text` and a `Value`. The former is displayed and the latter is used to identify the item.

If you want to have more columns in your `GridView` you can use a different `DataSource`. For example a `List<CustomClass>` or a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("Text");
tbl.Columns.Add("Value");
tbl.Columns.Add("FirstNamee");
tbl.Columns.Add("LastName");
tbl.Columns.Add("Addresss");

foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dirArr)
{
    // not sure how you get these informations from the DirectoryInfo 
    tbl.Rows.Add(Text, Value, FirstNamee, LastName, Addresss);
}
GridView.DataSource = tbl;
GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those are just sample parameters. I am going to pass file name, no.of folders, no. of files.

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom class, something like this,

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Text {get;set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
        public string Addresss {get;set;}
    }
```

Then you can add the objects into the list of type MyClass

```
 List<MyClass> files  = new List<MyClass>();             
 foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dirArr)
 {
            files.Add(new MyClass { Text = "", Value = "", FirstName = "", LastName = "", Addresss = "" });
 }
 GridView.DataSource = files;
 GridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is also helpfull, I found next answer is more helpful.